# How do I move the cart and search box for header

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to do this on my site but I can't do it.
[image]

I already tried this code but it didn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<body>  
    <move element="top.search" destination="panel.wrapper ."/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel"/>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code correct but some problem. you move tag add any reason dot sign(.)

And add this code :-

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel"/>
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" before="top.search"/>
```

After run `php bin/magento c:f`

output :-

[image]

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: I just copied the code and it didn't work.

Comment: default.xml file last add this code

Comment: Hello @AndresHiguita this is helpful or not ???